# React - syntax confusion to clarify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uppercase

I appreciate your help in getting me out of the mess i get into. I am very new to REACT and obviously tripping on some basic concepts.. Appreciate your kind help.

This is my app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem";
import todosData from "./components/todosData"

function App() {

  const todoComponents = todosData.map((todo) => (
    <TodoItem  key={todo.id} todo={todo.text} />
  ));
  console.log(todoComponents);

    return(
        <div className="todo-list">
          
            <todoComponents />,
          
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

todoData.js:

```
const todosData = [{
        id: "1",
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true,
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        text: "Grocery Shopping",
        completed: false,
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        text: "Clean Garage",
        completed: false,
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        text: "Mow Lawn",
        completed: false,
    },
    {
        id: "5",
        text: "Catch up on courses",
        completed: false,
    },
];
export default todosData;
```

Error screen with 'todoComponents' starting with lowercase 't'. Next screen will show errors when using uppercase T instead.

[image: ref1]

app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem";
import todosData from "./components/todosData"

function App() {

  const TodoComponents = todosData.map((todo) => (
    <TodoItem  key={todo.id} todo={todo.text} />
  ));
    
  console.log(TodoComponents);

    return(
        <div className="todo-list">
          
            <TodoComponents />,
          
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

**Error screen 2**

[image: ref2]

Kindly ask if you need more info

Comment: You have a comma behind the ``<TodoComponents />`` element. Unsure if that's actually the origin of the error though, just pointing that out.

Comment: `todoComponents` isn't a component, its an array. So it shouldn't be called as a component (`<  />`). Instead just render the array `{todoComponents}`

Comment: FYI - `React` components must start with a `capital letter` and 2 ways to create a `React` component : `class component` and `function component`. In this case, `todosData` is not a component because it's not following the `React` definition of a component. It's an `array` of items, so possibly putting that in your code would do the trick too! Also, WELCOME to the Stack Community, friend!

Answer (score 1):

TodoComponents is not a component which you imported, you have it set as a const. Try writing it like this:

```
return(
    <div className="todo-list">
      
        {todoComponents}
      
    </div>
)
```

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: your variable, `todoComponents` is an array of components. This does not make it a JSX component -- it is simply an array of JSX components.

JSX Components are either class-based, extending `React.Component` or `React.PureComponent` or they are a function that outputs JSX. The two examples of which are

```
class CustomComponent1 extends React.Component {
  render() { return "I am a component"; }
}

function CustomComponent2 () { 
  return "I am a second component";
}
```

Both of these may be called, either in their own files or in other JSX files, like so.

```
<CustomComponent1/>
<CustomComponent2/>
```

However, the following could *not* be called as a component

```
const SomeArray = ['hello','there'];

// Wrong
<SomeArray/>
// Right
<div>{SomeArray}</div>
```

The tl;dr of this lesson is that in React, unless it's a React Component (i.e. extended from one of the previous mentioned classes) or a functional component (a function that returns JSX) then it is ***not*** a component, and cannot be used like `<CustomComponent/>`.

Comment: I want to ask a quick question while on this issue: see my code of todoItem: