# A side question to my earlier question: ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, ternary

I want to ask you a quick question as a followup to my earlier question:
[React - syntax confusion to clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522496/react-syntax-confusion-to-clarify)

code for TodoItem:

```
import React from 'react'


export const TodoItem = (props) => {

    console.log(props)
    console.log(props.todo.completed)


    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={props.todo.completed} />
            <p>{props.todo.text} </p>
            <p>Completed: {props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No' </p>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem;
```

last field in props is  'props.todo.completed' thats a boolean. I am trying to decode it to yes/no based on if its true or false, but I cant seem to get the syntax right :(
I tried enclosing in backticks, {} but nothing seems to work ..
when i code :

Completed: {props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No'

shows up: Completed: ? 'Yes' : 'No'
when i code:

Completed: `{props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No'`

(adding backticks)
backticks show up: Completed:  `? 'Yes' : 'No'`
when i code:

Completed:{ `{props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No'`}

shows up: Completed:{props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No'

As you can see, i am struggling to get some basic concepts right in my head, and need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can write it like this

```
return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={props.todo.completed} />
            <p>{props.todo.text} </p>
            <p>Completed: {props.todo.completed ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>
            
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you use the `{}` in React when you want to write JavaScript instead of a String in the JSX. In that case:

`<p>Completed: {props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No' </p>`

means that everything outside the `{}` will be considered strings, so it will render:

`Completed (value of props.todo.completed) ? 'Yes' : 'No'`

Since the whole operation `props.todo.completed ? 'Yes': 'No'` is JavaScript, you should put all of it inside the `{}`, like this:

`<p>Completed: {props.todo.completed ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>`

This will render as:

`Completed: (Yes or No, depending on the value of props.todo.completed)`

Comment: Thanks Nilson.. I appreciate you taking time to explain this for me..

Comment: Sure! No problem. I hope you understood :)

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript expression you want to evaluate in `JSX` have to be wrapped inside the curly braces`{}`.

In your case, you want to evaluate a ternary expression so the whole expression has to wrapped inside the curly braces. For example,

```js
<p>Completed: { props.todo.completed ? 'Yes' : 'No' }</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing JSX, anything inside `{}` will be interpreted so in your example, you have `{props.todo.completed}` which interprets as `true`. The issue is that the ternary operation is outside of the curly braces, so it's never interpreted.

```
// ❌ not interpreting ternary operation 
{props.todo.completed} ? 'Yes' : 'No'

// ✅ interpreting ternary operation 
{props.todo.completed ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
```

In the second one, you are saying if `props.todo.completed` is true, return `Yes` string otherwise `No`.